# Datagrid if/then row calculation

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

In, C# I built a datatable connected to a datagrid which has three columns: id1, id2 and sum.

I want to add up id1 and id2 into column "sum", but only if sum is greater than x (x will be supplied from textbox1).

I have this code, but this defaults adding all the columns and doesnt allow for an if/then statement.

```
        column = new DataColumn();
        column.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Double");
        column.ColumnName = "sum";
        table.Columns.Add(column);
        table.Columns["sum"].Expression = "[id] * [id2]";
```

I thought about adding a foreach (Datarow row in table.Rows) (), but that doesnt allow me to create if then statements.

Answer (score 0):

presuming you have the value of x at this point, simply do a case statement in the expression.

Do something like -

```
table.Columns["sum"].Expression = "CASE WHEN [id] * [id2] > " + x + " THEN [id] * [id2] ELSE NULL END ";
```

BTW - do you want the product or the sum?  The column is named sum, but you are getting the product....just curious.

If you don't have x at the time of the query, you will have to do this in the ItemDataBound event of the DataGrid.  Have that sum column be a template column and calculate the value for it in the event.

Comment: I added the exact code you posted and got the following error: "Syntax error: Missing operand after 'WHEN' operator." table.Columns["sum"].Expression = "CASE WHEN ([id] * [id2]) > 7 THEN [id] * [id2] ELSE NULL END"; I dont even see a reference for such on option in Google search, only relating to SQL functions.

Comment: Found Microsoft's notes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx  But I dont see synatx for when.

Comment: This solved it:             table.Columns["sum"].Expression = "IIF([id] * [id2] > 7,1,[id] * [id2])";